# Unmet peer dependency React Native CLI Init

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-cli

I am trying to init a new react native project via the React Native CLI. I am on the most recent version (2.0.1)

[image: Version console output]

Then, I run the standard React Native Init command and the new project builds with all of these unmet peer dependency warnings:

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/nlegorrec/dev/test 

Using yarn v1.12.3
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.12.3
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > react-native@0.57.8" has unmet peer dependency "react@16.6.3".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 404 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ react-native@0.57.8
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@7.1.0
├─ @babel/helper-builder-react-jsx@7.3.0
├─ @babel/helper-call-delegate@7.1.0
├─ @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@7.3.0
├─ @babel/helper-define-map@7.1.0
├─ @babel/helper-explode-assignable-expression@7.1.0
├─ @babel/helper-hoist-variables@7.0.0
├─ @babel/helper-module-transforms@7.2.2
├─ @babel/helper-remap-async-to-generator@7.1.0
├─ @babel/helper-replace-supers@7.2.3
├─ @babel/helper-wrap-function@7.2.0
├─ @babel/helpers@7.3.1
├─ @babel/highlight@7.0.0
├─ @babel/parser@7.3.1
├─ @babel/plugin-external-helpers@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-flow@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoped-functions@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-object-super@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-property-literals@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.0.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.2.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.2.0
├─ @babel/register@7.0.0
├─ @babel/runtime@7.3.1
├─ abbrev@1.1.1
├─ accepts@1.3.5
├─ ansi-colors@1.1.0
├─ ansi-cyan@0.1.1
├─ ansi-escapes@3.1.0
├─ ansi-gray@0.1.1
├─ ansi-red@0.1.1
├─ ansi-styles@3.2.1
├─ ansi@0.3.1
├─ anymatch@2.0.0
├─ aproba@1.2.0
├─ are-we-there-yet@1.1.5
├─ argparse@1.0.10
├─ arr-flatten@1.1.0
├─ array-filter@0.0.1
├─ array-map@0.0.0
├─ array-reduce@0.0.0
├─ array-slice@0.2.3
├─ art@0.10.3
├─ asap@2.0.6
├─ assign-symbols@1.0.0
├─ async-limiter@1.0.0
├─ async@2.6.1
├─ atob@2.1.2
├─ babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas@7.0.0-beta.0
├─ babel-preset-fbjs@3.1.2
├─ balanced-match@1.0.0
├─ base@0.11.2
├─ base64-js@1.3.0
├─ basic-auth@2.0.1
├─ big-integer@1.6.41
├─ bplist-creator@0.0.7
├─ bplist-parser@0.1.1
├─ brace-expansion@1.1.11
├─ braces@2.3.2
├─ bser@2.0.0
├─ builtin-modules@1.1.1
├─ bytes@3.0.0
├─ cache-base@1.0.1
├─ caller-callsite@2.0.0
├─ caller-path@2.0.0
├─ callsites@2.0.0
├─ capture-exit@1.2.0
├─ chardet@0.4.2
├─ chownr@1.1.1
├─ class-utils@0.3.6
├─ cli-cursor@2.1.0
├─ cli-width@2.2.0
├─ cliui@3.2.0
├─ code-point-at@1.1.0
├─ collection-visit@1.0.0
├─ color-convert@1.9.3
├─ color-name@1.1.3
├─ color-support@1.1.3
├─ commander@2.19.0
├─ commondir@1.0.1
├─ compressible@2.0.15
├─ compression@1.7.3
├─ concat-map@0.0.1
├─ concat-stream@1.6.2
├─ console-control-strings@1.1.0
├─ convert-source-map@1.6.0
├─ copy-descriptor@0.1.1
├─ core-js@2.6.3
├─ core-util-is@1.0.2
├─ cosmiconfig@5.0.7
├─ create-react-class@15.6.3
├─ cross-spawn@5.1.0
├─ debug@2.6.9
├─ decamelize@1.2.0
├─ decode-uri-component@0.2.0
├─ deep-extend@0.6.0
├─ delegates@1.0.0
├─ destroy@1.0.4
├─ detect-libc@1.0.3
├─ detect-newline@2.1.0
├─ dom-walk@0.1.1
├─ ee-first@1.1.1
├─ encoding@0.1.12
├─ envinfo@5.12.1
├─ error-ex@1.3.2
├─ errorhandler@1.5.0
├─ esprima@4.0.1
├─ esutils@2.0.2
├─ etag@1.8.1
├─ event-target-shim@1.1.1
├─ eventemitter3@3.1.0
├─ execa@0.7.0
├─ expand-brackets@2.1.4
├─ expand-range@1.8.2
├─ external-editor@2.2.0
├─ extglob@2.0.4
├─ fancy-log@1.3.3
├─ fbjs-css-vars@1.0.2
├─ fbjs-scripts@1.0.1
├─ figures@2.0.0
├─ filename-regex@2.0.1
├─ fill-range@4.0.0
├─ finalhandler@1.1.0
├─ find-cache-dir@1.0.0
├─ find-up@2.1.0
├─ for-in@1.0.2
├─ for-own@0.1.5
├─ fresh@0.5.2
├─ fs-minipass@1.2.5
├─ fs.realpath@1.0.0
├─ fsevents@1.2.7
├─ gauge@1.2.7
├─ get-caller-file@1.0.3
├─ get-stream@3.0.0
├─ get-value@2.0.6
├─ glob-base@0.3.0
├─ glob-parent@2.0.0
├─ glob@7.1.3
├─ global@4.3.2
├─ growly@1.3.0
├─ has-ansi@2.0.0
├─ has-flag@3.0.0
├─ has-unicode@2.0.1
├─ has-value@1.0.0
├─ has-values@1.0.0
├─ home-or-tmp@3.0.0
├─ hosted-git-info@2.7.1
├─ http-errors@1.6.3
├─ iconv-lite@0.4.24
├─ ignore-walk@3.0.1
├─ image-size@0.6.3
├─ import-fresh@2.0.0
├─ imurmurhash@0.1.4
├─ inflight@1.0.6
├─ inherits@2.0.3
├─ ini@1.3.5
├─ inquirer@3.3.0
├─ invariant@2.2.4
├─ invert-kv@1.0.0
├─ is-accessor-descriptor@1.0.0
├─ is-arrayish@0.2.1
├─ is-builtin-module@1.0.0
├─ is-data-descriptor@1.0.0
├─ is-descriptor@1.0.2
├─ is-directory@0.3.1
├─ is-dotfile@1.0.3
├─ is-equal-shallow@0.1.3
├─ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
├─ is-plain-object@2.0.4
├─ is-posix-bracket@0.1.1
├─ is-primitive@2.0.0
├─ is-promise@2.1.0
├─ is-stream@1.1.0
├─ is-windows@1.0.2
├─ isarray@1.0.0
├─ isexe@2.0.0
├─ jest-docblock@23.2.0
├─ jest-serializer@23.0.1
├─ jest-worker@23.2.0
├─ js-tokens@4.0.0
├─ js-yaml@3.12.1
├─ jsesc@2.5.2
├─ json-parse-better-errors@1.0.2
├─ json-stable-stringify@1.0.1
├─ json5@2.1.0
├─ jsonfile@2.4.0
├─ kind-of@3.2.2
├─ klaw@1.3.1
├─ lcid@1.0.0
├─ load-json-file@2.0.0
├─ locate-path@2.0.0
├─ lodash.pad@4.5.1
├─ lodash.padend@4.6.1
├─ lodash.padstart@4.6.1
├─ lru-cache@4.1.5
├─ make-dir@1.3.0
├─ makeerror@1.0.11
├─ map-visit@1.0.0
├─ math-random@1.0.4
├─ mem@1.1.0
├─ merge@1.2.1
├─ metro-babel-register@0.48.5
├─ metro-babel7-plugin-react-transform@0.48.5
├─ metro-config@0.48.5
├─ metro-memory-fs@0.48.5
├─ metro-minify-uglify@0.48.5
├─ metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.48.5
├─ metro-source-map@0.48.5
├─ metro@0.48.5
├─ mime-db@1.37.0
├─ mime-types@2.1.11
├─ mime@1.6.0
├─ min-document@2.19.0
├─ minimatch@3.0.4
├─ minimist@1.2.0
├─ minizlib@1.2.1
├─ mixin-deep@1.3.1
├─ mkdirp@0.5.1
├─ morgan@1.9.1
├─ mute-stream@0.0.7
├─ nan@2.12.1
├─ nanomatch@1.2.13
├─ needle@2.2.4
├─ negotiator@0.6.1
├─ node-int64@0.4.0
├─ node-modules-regexp@1.0.0
├─ node-notifier@5.3.0
├─ node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
├─ nopt@4.0.1
├─ normalize-package-data@2.4.0
├─ normalize-path@2.1.1
├─ npm-bundled@1.0.5
├─ npm-packlist@1.2.0
├─ npm-run-path@2.0.2
├─ npmlog@2.0.4
├─ nullthrows@1.1.1
├─ number-is-nan@1.0.1
├─ object-assign@4.1.1
├─ object-copy@0.1.0
├─ object.omit@2.0.1
├─ onetime@2.0.1
├─ opn@3.0.3
├─ optimist@0.6.1
├─ options@0.0.6
├─ os-homedir@1.0.2
├─ os-locale@2.1.0
├─ os-tmpdir@1.0.2
├─ osenv@0.1.5
├─ p-finally@1.0.0
├─ p-limit@1.3.0
├─ p-locate@2.0.0
├─ p-try@1.0.0
├─ parse-glob@3.0.4
├─ parse-json@4.0.0
├─ parse-node-version@1.0.0
├─ pascalcase@0.1.1
├─ path-exists@3.0.0
├─ path-is-absolute@1.0.1
├─ path-key@2.0.1
├─ path-parse@1.0.6
├─ path-type@2.0.0
├─ pirates@4.0.0
├─ pkg-dir@2.0.0
├─ plist@3.0.1
├─ plugin-error@0.1.2
├─ posix-character-classes@0.1.1
├─ preserve@0.2.0
├─ pretty-format@4.3.1
├─ private@0.1.8
├─ process-nextick-args@2.0.0
├─ process@0.5.2
├─ prop-types@15.6.2
├─ pseudomap@1.0.2
├─ randomatic@3.1.1
├─ range-parser@1.2.0
├─ rc@1.2.8
├─ react-clone-referenced-element@1.1.0
├─ react-deep-force-update@1.1.2
├─ react-devtools-core@3.6.0
├─ react-native@0.57.8
├─ react-proxy@1.1.8
├─ react-timer-mixin@0.13.4
├─ read-pkg-up@2.0.0
├─ read-pkg@2.0.0
├─ readable-stream@2.3.6
├─ regenerate-unicode-properties@7.0.0
├─ regenerator-runtime@0.11.1
├─ regenerator-transform@0.13.3
├─ regex-cache@0.4.4
├─ regex-not@1.0.2
├─ regexpu-core@4.4.0
├─ regjsgen@0.5.0
├─ regjsparser@0.6.0
├─ remove-trailing-separator@1.1.0
├─ require-directory@2.1.1
├─ require-main-filename@1.0.1
├─ resolve-from@3.0.0
├─ resolve-url@0.2.1
├─ resolve@1.10.0
├─ restore-cursor@2.0.0
├─ ret@0.1.15
├─ rimraf@2.6.3
├─ rsvp@3.6.2
├─ run-async@2.3.0
├─ rx-lite-aggregates@4.0.8
├─ rx-lite@4.0.8
├─ safer-buffer@2.1.2
├─ sane@2.5.2
├─ sax@1.1.6
├─ semver@5.6.0
├─ send@0.16.2
├─ serialize-error@2.1.0
├─ serve-static@1.13.2
├─ set-blocking@2.0.0
├─ set-value@2.0.0
├─ setprototypeof@1.1.0
├─ shebang-command@1.2.0
├─ shebang-regex@1.0.0
├─ shell-quote@1.6.1
├─ shellwords@0.1.1
├─ signal-exit@3.0.2
├─ simple-plist@0.2.1
├─ slide@1.1.6
├─ snapdragon-node@2.1.1
├─ snapdragon-util@3.0.1
├─ source-map-resolve@0.5.2
├─ source-map-support@0.5.10
├─ source-map-url@0.4.0
├─ spdx-correct@3.1.0
├─ spdx-exceptions@2.2.0
├─ split-string@3.1.0
├─ sprintf-js@1.0.3
├─ stacktrace-parser@0.1.4
├─ static-extend@0.1.2
├─ statuses@1.3.1
├─ stream-buffers@2.2.0
├─ string_decoder@1.1.1
├─ string-width@1.0.2
├─ strip-ansi@3.0.1
├─ strip-bom@3.0.0
├─ strip-eof@1.0.0
├─ strip-json-comments@2.0.1
├─ supports-color@2.0.0
├─ tar@4.4.8
├─ temp@0.8.3
├─ throat@4.1.0
├─ through@2.3.8
├─ through2@2.0.5
├─ time-stamp@1.1.0
├─ tmp@0.0.33
├─ tmpl@1.0.4
├─ to-fast-properties@2.0.0
├─ to-regex-range@2.1.1
├─ trim-right@1.0.1
├─ typedarray@0.0.6
├─ uglify-es@3.3.9
├─ ultron@1.0.2
├─ unicode-canonical-property-names-ecmascript@1.0.4
├─ unicode-match-property-ecmascript@1.0.4
├─ unicode-match-property-value-ecmascript@1.0.2
├─ unicode-property-aliases-ecmascript@1.0.4
├─ union-value@1.0.0
├─ unpipe@1.0.0
├─ unset-value@1.0.0
├─ urix@0.1.0
├─ use@3.1.1
├─ util-deprecate@1.0.2
├─ utils-merge@1.0.1
├─ uuid@3.3.2
├─ validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4
├─ vary@1.1.2
├─ walker@1.0.7
├─ watch@0.18.0
├─ whatwg-fetch@3.0.0
├─ which-module@2.0.0
├─ which@1.3.1
├─ wide-align@1.1.3
├─ wrap-ansi@2.1.0
├─ write-file-atomic@1.3.4
├─ ws@1.1.5
├─ xcode@1.1.0
├─ xmlbuilder@9.0.7
├─ xmldoc@0.4.0
├─ xpipe@1.0.5
├─ xtend@4.0.1
├─ y18n@3.2.1
├─ yallist@3.0.3
└─ yargs-parser@7.0.0
✨  Done in 11.76s.
Setting up new React Native app in /Users/nlegorrec/dev/test
Adding React...
yarn add v1.12.3
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 2 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ react@16.6.3
info All dependencies
├─ react@16.6.3
└─ scheduler@0.11.3
✨  Done in 2.65s.
Adding Jest...
yarn add v1.12.3
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning jest > jest-cli > prompts > kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.2.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-literals@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning " > babel-jest@23.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-0".
warning " > babel-jest@23.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-0".
warning " > metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.51.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 130 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ babel-jest@23.6.0
├─ jest@23.6.0
├─ metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.51.1
└─ react-test-renderer@16.6.3
info All dependencies
├─ acorn-globals@4.3.0
├─ acorn-walk@6.1.1
├─ acorn@5.7.3
├─ ajv@6.7.0
├─ append-transform@0.4.0
├─ array-equal@1.0.0
├─ arrify@1.0.1
├─ asn1@0.2.4
├─ astral-regex@1.0.0
├─ asynckit@0.4.0
├─ aws-sign2@0.7.0
├─ aws4@1.8.0
├─ babel-core@6.26.3
├─ babel-generator@6.26.1
├─ babel-helpers@6.24.1
├─ babel-jest@23.6.0
├─ babel-plugin-jest-hoist@23.2.0
├─ babel-register@6.26.0
├─ babel-template@6.26.0
├─ babel-traverse@6.26.0
├─ bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.2
├─ browser-process-hrtime@0.1.3
├─ browser-resolve@1.11.3
├─ caseless@0.12.0
├─ ci-info@1.6.0
├─ cliui@4.1.0
├─ co@4.6.0
├─ combined-stream@1.0.7
├─ cssom@0.3.4
├─ cssstyle@1.1.1
├─ dashdash@1.14.1
├─ data-urls@1.1.0
├─ deep-is@0.1.3
├─ default-require-extensions@1.0.0
├─ delayed-stream@1.0.0
├─ detect-indent@4.0.0
├─ diff@3.5.0
├─ domexception@1.0.1
├─ ecc-jsbn@0.1.2
├─ es-abstract@1.13.0
├─ es-to-primitive@1.2.0
├─ escodegen@1.11.0
├─ estraverse@4.2.0
├─ expect@23.6.0
├─ extend@3.0.2
├─ extsprintf@1.3.0
├─ fast-deep-equal@2.0.1
├─ fast-levenshtein@2.0.6
├─ fileset@2.0.3
├─ forever-agent@0.6.1
├─ form-data@2.3.3
├─ getpass@0.1.7
├─ handlebars@4.0.12
├─ har-schema@2.0.0
├─ har-validator@5.1.3
├─ has-symbols@1.0.0
├─ has@1.0.3
├─ html-encoding-sniffer@1.0.2
├─ http-signature@1.2.0
├─ ip-regex@3.0.0
├─ is-date-object@1.0.1
├─ is-finite@1.0.2
├─ is-generator-fn@1.0.0
├─ is-regex@1.0.4
├─ is-symbol@1.0.2
├─ is-typedarray@1.0.0
├─ is-utf8@0.2.1
├─ isstream@0.1.2
├─ istanbul-api@1.3.7
├─ istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.2
├─ istanbul-lib-report@1.1.5
├─ istanbul-lib-source-maps@1.2.6
├─ istanbul-reports@1.5.1
├─ jest-changed-files@23.4.2
├─ jest-cli@23.6.0
├─ jest-each@23.6.0
├─ jest-environment-node@23.4.0
├─ jest-leak-detector@23.6.0
├─ jest-resolve-dependencies@23.6.0
├─ jest-runner@23.6.0
├─ jest-watcher@23.4.0
├─ jest@23.6.0
├─ jsdom@11.12.0
├─ json-schema-traverse@0.4.1
├─ json-schema@0.2.3
├─ json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
├─ jsprim@1.4.1
├─ kleur@2.0.2
├─ left-pad@1.3.0
├─ leven@2.1.0
├─ levn@0.3.0
├─ metro-babel7-plugin-react-transform@0.51.1
├─ metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.51.1
├─ natural-compare@1.4.0
├─ nwsapi@2.0.9
├─ oauth-sign@0.9.0
├─ object.getownpropertydescriptors@2.0.3
├─ optionator@0.8.2
├─ parse5@4.0.0
├─ performance-now@2.1.0
├─ pinkie@2.0.4
├─ pn@1.1.0
├─ prompts@0.1.14
├─ qs@6.5.2
├─ react-is@16.7.0
├─ react-test-renderer@16.6.3
├─ repeating@2.0.1
├─ request-promise-core@1.1.1
├─ request-promise-native@1.0.5
├─ request@2.88.0
├─ resolve-cwd@2.0.0
├─ sisteransi@0.1.1
├─ sshpk@1.16.0
├─ stack-utils@1.0.2
├─ stealthy-require@1.1.1
├─ symbol-tree@3.2.2
├─ test-exclude@4.2.3
├─ tough-cookie@2.5.0
├─ tunnel-agent@0.6.0
├─ tweetnacl@0.14.5
├─ uglify-js@3.4.9
├─ uri-js@4.2.2
├─ util.promisify@1.0.0
├─ verror@1.10.0
├─ w3c-hr-time@1.0.1
├─ whatwg-encoding@1.0.5
├─ whatwg-mimetype@2.3.0
├─ whatwg-url@6.5.0
├─ xml-name-validator@3.0.0
└─ yargs-parser@9.0.2
✨  Done in 5.60s.
```

When I ignore the warnings and run the app on ios with react-native run-ios the bundle fails with the error:

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: /Users/nlegorrec/dev/campus-app/campus_hybrid/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Switch/Switch.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'nullishCoalescingOperator' isn't currently enabled (167:52):
```

I am not sure if the warnings have anything to do with this bundle error but ultimately I need to get the ios app running on my simulator. So I thought the warnings were a good place to start.

Please let me know if you have seen this and have any advice.

Comment: Not to mention I am getting a ton of compiling warnings before react-native run-ios ultimately fails. All of this is happening from what I believe is a fresh install of react-native-cli and a new react-native init project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue today and indeed not encouraging to have warnings on a fresh new project. 
I just add babel core manually `yarn add  babel-core@^6.0.0`and did not had pbs to run the new app.